# Pass subscribe result to onNext

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, observable

I have a function that fetches some info from a web service:

```
const rxjs = require('rxjs');
const request = require('request');
const moment = require('moment');
function getAvailableGroupClasses() {
    return rxjs.Observable.create(observable => {
        request(`https://myservice.com/get.json`, (error, response, body) => {
            const j = JSON.parse(body);
            observable.next(j);
            observable.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

It returns an observable that is then susbcribed by another function:

```
function findClassOnDateTime(className, targetDateTime) {
    return rxjs.Observable.create(observable => {
        getAvailableGroupClasses().subscribe(classes => {
            classes.getAllGroupClassesMap
            .filter(value => value.nomeAtividade === className) // filter by name
            .filter(value => moment(`${value.day} ${value.time}`, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').isSame(momentTargetDateTime, 'minute')) //filter by class date
            .map(values => observable.next(values)) // wrap this in an observable, call here next
        });
    });
}
```

Finally, the façade will call `findClassOnDateTime` like this:

```
findClassOnDateTime('classname', moment().day(1 + 7).hour(19).minute(20)).subscribe(values => {
    console.log(values);
});
```

My issue is in the function `findClassOnDateTime` . It subscribes an Observable and creates a new one to pass along the value. Although it is working I've been reading online that Observables should not be linked or nested but I've not seen any example for when one has to create the observable and not only subscribe to it.

Just like to point out that the façade should not call `getAvailableGroupClasses` and then `findClassOnDateTime`, it must be all done in `findClassOnDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`, `filter` and many more operators directly on `observable`. Actually you are reimplementing the `map` operator each time you create a new observable.

I am guessing `getAllGroupClassesMap` is an array. You can convert the array to observable with `Observable.from` and chain all of the operators.

```
function createHttpObservable(url) {
   return Observable.create(observer => {
      request(url, (error, response, body) => {
         const j = JSON.parse(body);
         observer.next(j);
         observer.complete();
      });
   });
}

function findClassOnDateTime(className, targetDateTime) {
   return createHttpObservable("https://myservice.com/get.json").concatMap(r => Observable.from(r.getAllGroupClassesMap))
      .filter(value => value.nomeAtividade === className)
      .filter(value => moment(`${value.day} ${value.time}`, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').isSame(targetDateTime, 'minute'));
}

findClassOnDateTime("..." , xxxx).subscribe(values =>  console.log(values));
```